# How to store UUID fields in Java classes?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

I work on an android project and have performance problems with UUID fields. Here is the project sample code (not written by me):

```
public class OrderVo {

@Expose
@SerializedName("UId")
private UUID mGuId;

public String getGuId() {
    return UUIDHelper.toString(mGuId);
}

public void setGuId(String guId) {
    mGuId = UUIDHelper.fromString(guId);
}
...
```

This object is used in RecyclerView and its methods are called in bindData of the adapter. This causes a performance issue cause on every scroll getGuId() is called and String objects are created from UUID and GC is actively working to clean that objects (and that causes lag when fast scrolling). Is there any benefits of keeping mGuId field as UUID and not a simple String?

Comment: If your method operates on `String` objects, why to you need to use `UUID` at all? Generate it as `UUID`, store as `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the callers do not convert the UUID-string back to a string you can indeed store the values as `String`.

One drawback with this solution is the missing type checking. The string must not contain a UUID but can contain anything else.